# SwiftUI changing State variable in code does not refresh list

Tags: swiftui, nspredicate, swiftui-state

I have a list of matches and when I type in the filter (TextField) it works fine.  I also have a list of players the user can pick from.  When they choose a player the func playerFilterChanged is called and usernameSearch is updated from the viewModel.  I put a breakpoint on matches.nsPredicate = ... in the TextField onChange event and it is hit but the list doesn't update.  Am I binding something incorrectly?

```
struct MatchHistory: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: ViewModel
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "datetime", ascending: false)], animation: .default)
    private var matches: FetchedResults<Match>
    @Binding var showMatchHistory : Bool
    @Binding var showChangePlayer : Bool
    var cellPadding : CGFloat = 5
    var deviceType = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom
    @State private var orientation = UIDeviceOrientation.unknown
    @State var showLoadingMessage : Bool = true
    @State private var usernameSearch = ""
    
    func playerFilterChanged(){
        usernameSearch = viewModel.filterPlayerName
        showChangePlayer = false
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geometry in
            if(showLoadingMessage){
                VStack{
                    Spacer()
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Loading...").font(.largeTitle)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            } else {
                    Form{
                        Section(header: Text("Filter by Player")){
                            HStack{
                                Text("Player Name")
                                HStack{
                                    TextField("", text: $usernameSearch).disabled(false)
                                        .onChange(of: usernameSearch){
                                        newValue in
                                        if(newValue.isEmpty == false){
                                            let p0 = NSPredicate(format: "player1Record.playerName CONTAINS[cd] %@", newValue)
                                            let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "player2Record.playerName CONTAINS[cd] %@", newValue)
                                            matches.nsPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p0, p1])
                                        }
                                    }
                                    Button("Clear Filter"){
                                        viewModel.filterPlayerName = ""
                                        usernameSearch = ""
                                    }
                                    Spacer()
                                    Button("Filter by Player"){
                                        showChangePlayer = true
                                    }.sheet(isPresented: $showChangePlayer, onDismiss: playerFilterChanged){
                                        FilterPlayer()
                                    }
                                }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                                    .padding(10).background(Color.darkGray).cornerRadius(16)
                            }
                        }
                        List {
                            ForEach(matches) { Match in
                                Section(header: Text(FormatDate(datetime: Match.datetime))){
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                        HStack{
                                            Group{
                                                Text("Player Name").frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.3, alignment:.center).padding(cellPadding)
                                                Text("1").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity).padding(cellPadding)
                                                Text("2").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity).padding(cellPadding)
                                                Text("3").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity).padding(cellPadding)
                                                Text("4").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity).padding(cellPadding)
                                                Text("5").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity).padding(cellPadding)
                                                if(Match.boardType == "N"){
                                                    Text("Total").frame(width: 50).padding(cellPadding)
                                                }
                                            }
                                            if(Match.boardType == "W"){
                                                Group{
                                                    Text("6").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity).padding(cellPadding)
                                                    Text("7").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity).padding(cellPadding)
                                                    Text("8").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity).padding(cellPadding)
                                                    Text("9").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity).padding(cellPadding)
                                                    Text("10").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity).padding(cellPadding)
                                                    Text("Total").frame(width: 50).padding(cellPadding)
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }.background(Match.boardType == "W" ? Color.blue : Color.darkGreen).cornerRadius(16)
                                        MatchHistoryScoreRow(geometry: geometry, Match: Match, player: "player1", cellPadding: cellPadding)
                                        if(Match.gameType != "singlePlayer"){
                                            MatchHistoryScoreRow(geometry: geometry, Match: Match, player: "player2", cellPadding: cellPadding)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }.padding(.top, 10)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? No one can run this code